# Spider-Man: Homecoming sequel?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-homecoming, sequel

Is Marvel going to make another movie that follows what happens after **Spider-Man: Homecoming**.

Comment: If you wrote the exact same text into that little box on Google.com you would have gotten an answer by now

Comment: @Raditz_35 That's what I did and the first result gave me the answer --> http://www.digitalspy.com/movies/spider-man/feature/a832366/spider-man-2-release-date-cast-plot-and-everything-you-need-to-know/

Comment: While yes, it is easy to get the answer, canonical statements don't _necessarily_ serve themselves on a plate. I suggest OP edit their question to focus on official statements.

Comment: Marvel? Make another movie? Well, we can *hope* I guess.

Comment: Also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man:_Homecoming#Sequels) is usually good for this sort of stuff.

Comment: I mean, you've still got Spider-Man: Prom, Spider-Man: Sadie Hawkins, Spider-Man: Enchantment Under the Sea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Most likely, but not necessarily "Homecoming 2"

Tom Holland himself has confirmed that he is contracted to three solo films and three "other" films (likely joint films with Avengers, etc):

> They give you options and those could be exercised whenever. Like a cameo in Avengers," Holland says of Marvel. "I'm unclear as to which movies though. I do know I have three Spider-Man [appearances in other] movies and **three solo movies contracted**...
> <sub>['Spider-Man': Tom Holland Reveals How Many Marvel Films He's Signed For - The Hollywood Reporter](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/spider-man-tom-holland-how-movies-will-he-be-945566)</sub>

While this may not specifically be titled "Homecoming 2" we can expect at least 2 more Spider-Man sequel films, starring Tom Holland, as well as at least two more films (as of the date of writing) featuring Spider-Man amongst other title characters.

Kevin Feige, Marvel Studios President, had stated (before the release of the Homecoming) that if they were to make sequels, taking on an approach to the Harry Potter stories was something they had in mind from early on.

> Should we be able to make more after that? Sure. **This is sophomore year, is the next one junior year? Is the next one senior year? Is there a summer break between each of those?** I don’t know what, but it was sort of how do we do a journey for Peter **not dissimilar for what the students of Hogwarts would go through each of their years, which was one of the early ideas we had for the movies.**
> <sub>[Kevin Feige Says ‘Spider-Man’ Sequels Could Follow the ‘Harry Potter’ Format - Collider](http://collider.com/spider-man-homecoming-sequels-harry-potter/)</sub>

Comment: In my experience, having an imdb page for an upcoming movie is about as trustworthy as dreaming about it. Maybe you should consider linking a more reliable source.

Comment: That's why I'd provided a direct quote from Tom Holland. But sure, I'll remove the IMDB link.

Comment: Being contracted for a film does not necessarily mean a film will be made. The studios often buy rights and sign contracts with actors with options for multiple movies just in case.

Comment: @phantom42 considering you dislike absolutes, better?

Comment: This answer should probably be updated to include Far From Home, but I guess that kind of defeats the purpose and timing of this question.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new [trailer](https://www.marvel.com/movies/spider-man-far-from-home) out for the *Spider-Man: Far from Home* film [starring](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6320628/) Tom Holland, to be released in the summer of 2019. The trailer strongly implies that it builds upon the immediate aftermath of *Avengers: Endgame*, primarily the

> Death of Tony Stark.

It contains an official warning that it contains major spoilers for that movie.